# How do I read from /data/app folder in android(with android studio,i mean by code)?

Tags: android

There are some apps that read from this folder without any root access,I know some of the folders in /data requires root access,but I think this /data/app does not(there are some app that constantly access the data(s) inside it,like shareit,or any apk backup/share app),but I am always getting Exceptoions if I try to read or access any file/folder in /data/app folder. Please help. The code and the exceptions are bellow:

```
File[] files=new File("/data/app").listFiles();
    for(int i=0;i<files.length;++i) {
        System.out.println(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Exceptions:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ragib.app_from_scratch, PID: 9293
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ragib.app_from_scratch/com.example.ragib.app_from_scratch.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
                      at com.example.ragib.app_from_scratch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

I used FX file explorer to see if the folder is empty, but it was not, there was some folders(as some apps were installed). But I was unable to list those by my code.

Please have a look.
Thanks...
Screenshots are bellow(see the links)

[Inside /data/app folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7bNG.png)

[Inside /data/app/com.facebook... folder, i even copied it from here to my sd card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPOzB.png)

Comment: Catch that NullPointerException! But better check if listFiles() returns null and do not continue if so but return; Adapt your code here please.

Comment: `there are some app that constantly access the data(s) inside it` How do you know? Hard to believe. And... what is in it that you wanna list?

Comment: `(with android studio,....)?` Nonsense. With an Android app on your Android device you mean.

Comment: `I used FX file explorer to see if the folder is empty,` ?? Then can you browse the /data folder too with that app? If not: how do you browse to /data/app with it?

Comment: 'files' is null,i checked... And, for the line 'there are some app that constantly ...', please install FX file explorer (on a non-rooted device), it can access and even copy files from that(/data/app) directory. But most of other folders are inaccessible. FX explorer is just one example, ES file explorer and many apk backup app access that folder,I checked that, but i don't remember which one, but i am sure they do... anyways, I don't know much about all these, I am just a beginner. Sorry if I am wrong, but I am just saying how can they access it without root access ? That is all...
Thanks..

Comment: Please show a screenshot of FX displaying the contents of /data/app. Do it so that we can see that it is indeed /data/app.

Comment: `Sorry if I am wrong, but I am just saying how can they access it without root access ? ` If listFiles() returns null then you can't.

Comment: Dear greenapps, with ''(with android studio,....)?" ,I meant that it should be done by code, node by any other applications.

Comment: By your app. Thats what you want. Android Studio has nothing to do with it. You could as well have used Eclipse or yet another IDE. So... Nonsense.

Comment: God! have you got what I meant? I think that is enough. You are not asked to check the spelling or anything.

Comment: Mmmm I installed FX explorer and indeed it shows a lot of folders in /data. Also the app folder. And /data/app contains a lot of application. which upon opened show a lib folder and a base.apk file. All on a non rooted device. Never saw such.

Comment: Thanks for admitting...